# Can I bind RadWindow client-side event to a code behind function?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I know it's usually a javascript function. But can I bind RadWindow client-side event(e.g. onclientclose) to a code behind function? If not, how to call the code behind function from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate a postback, for example, from a hidden button or something.

```
function OnClientCloseHandler(sender, args) {
  //do your work
  //perhaps store data in a hidden field

  //initiate a postback, for example:
  __doPostBack("", "");

}
```

THere are other ways to do this. If you have a button whose click you want to emulate, use this:

```
__doPostBack("<%=theButtonID.UniqueID%>", "");
```

if this button performs a partial postback it will do so with this code. The UniqueID on the server is the name attribute of the DOM object.

If you use more Telerik, you can invoke a partial postback through the RadAjaxManager: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-client-side-api.html.

Comment: Thanks, rdmptn! It definitely helps!!